# passport.js successful authentication not calling next()

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am using passport.js for authentication. It seems that upon successful authentication, passport does not call `next()`, so my Express route is never executed. I see this behavior for both authentication strategies I've implemented.

**app.js**

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(authentication.local);
passport.use(authentication.bearer);

routes.setup(app, passport);
```

**routes.js**

```
function setup (app, passport) {
  // routes.authentication.token not called, despite successful authentication.
  app.post('/authentication/token', passport.authenticate('local'), 
      routes.authentication.token);
}
```

**authentication.js**

```
var local = new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },

  function (email, password, done) {
    var user = new User({ email: email });

    user.fetch({
      success: function (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.get('encryptedPassword'))) {
          // This line shows in the console, but the route after is never executed.
          console.log("LocalStrategy success!");
          done(null, user); // Tell passport we have success.
        } else {
          done(null, false, { message: 'The password given was incorrect.' });
        }
      },

      error: function (err) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'The email address (' + email + ') does not belong to any user.' });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a one-file replication of the issue, which may be easier to follow than the incomplete, multi-file issue above:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Environment/Configuration
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var config =  require('./lib/config');

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
config.load(__dirname + '/config/environment', environment);
config.loadDev(__dirname + '/config/environment', environment);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Requirements
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var express = require('express')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , User = require('./app/models/user');


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// HTTP Server
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var app = express();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Middleware
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },

  function (email, password, done) {
    console.log("Authenticating user.", email, password);
    var user = new User({ email: email });

    user.fetch({
      success: function (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.get('encryptedPassword'))) {
          // This log statement shows in the console.
          console.log("LocalStrategy success!");
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          done(null, false, { message: 'The password given was incorrect.' });
        }
      },

      error: function (err) {
        console.log('LocalStrategy failure!');
        done(null, false, { message: 'The email address (' + email + ') does not belong to any user.' });
      },

      complete: function (user, res) {
        console.log(res);
      }
    });
  }
));

app.post('/authentication/token', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res, next) {
  // This line is never reached.
  console.log('I\'m authenticated!');
});

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Boot
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
console.log('Server started on port: %d', process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: Where is routes.authentication.token defined ? There is no route in routes.js.

Comment: @user568109 It's defined elsewhere in the file. If I replace routes.authentication.token with a function that calls console.log(), that function is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to have the ordering of the Express middleware. `app.use(passport.initialize());` and passport setup needs to come *before* `app.use(app.router);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i'd accidentally removed the callback from my serializeUser function.

Maybe check that both your serialization and deserialization functions are correct.

The code below is what i use, yours will probably differ, depending on if you are using the id of your user to serialize, or a different field.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not using sessions because this is for an API, so I'm also not using serializeUser or deserializeUser. I've tried turning on sessions and adding user serialization, but it doesn't help.

Comment: If you're not using session, you should disable them in your authenticate call: `passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });`